# updating checkboxes when stored in table as 0 or 1

Tags: php, checkbox, binary, updating

i have stored data values in a table using checkboxes where values are stored either as 1(service available) and 0 (not available). how do i update checkbox info. 
   INSERTING

```
<?php
$chkbox = array('antenatal', 'arvtherapy','basicemergencyobstericcare',`'bloodtransfusion', 'caesereansection', 'curativeinpatient', 'curativeoutpatient', 'familyplanning', 'vct', 'homebasedcare', 'immunization', 'imofci', 'radiology', 'ruralhealthtraining', 'tuberculosis', 'cardiology','physiotherapy', 'spinalinjury', 'dental', 'optical');

if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
{
if(isset($_GET['id']))
 $id= $_GET['id'];   
$serviceno = $_POST['serviceno'];
$values = array();
foreach($chkbox as $selection )
{     if(in_array($selection, $serviceno))
        { $values[ $selection ] = 1;  }
    else
        { $values[ $selection ] = 0;  }
     } // end of foreach.

 $insert = "INSERT INTO hospitalservices (id,antenatal, arvtherapy,   basicemergencyobstericcare, bloodtransfusion, caesereansection, curativeinpatient, curativeoutpatient, familyplanning, vct, homebasedcare, immunization, imofci, radiology, ruralhealthtraining, tuberculosis, cardiology, physiotherapy, spinalinjury, dental, optical)
      VALUES ('$id',{$values['antenatal']}, {$values['arvtherapy']},     {$values['basicemergencyobstericcare']}, {$values['bloodtransfusion']}, {$values['caesereansection']}, {$values['curativeinpatient']}, {$values['curativeoutpatient']}, {$values['familyplanning']}, {$values['vct']}, {$values['homebasedcare']}, {$values['immunization']}, {$values['imofci']}, {$values['radiology']}, {$values['ruralhealthtraining']}, {$values['tuberculosis']}, {$values['cardiology']}, {$values['physiotherapy']}, {$values['spinalinjury']}, {$values['dental']}, {$values['optical']})";
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Update the table or display checkboxes which are pre-checked or not, according to the data stored in the table?

Comment: You have an erroneous back tic in the array declaration that is breaking the syntax highlighting. Right before blood transfusion.

Comment: jwulf, display the textboxes that were peviously prechecked then update the checkboxes by selecting or unselecting, they're 20 checkboxes